# LASSO Logistic Regression & Platt Scaling

Tags: machine-learning, model, lasso, biostatistics, calibration

I recently built a cross-validated (10 folds) LASSO logistic regression model to make binary predictions within STATA. Interestingly, the model calibration was initially poor:

[image]

Realizing that the distribution of predicted probabilities has somewhat of a sigmoid lowess curve, I figured I can apply a linear transformation using an application of the basic sigmoid function:

y = 1/(1+exp(-x))

After optimizing the above equation + substituting my initial model predictions for x, I was able to generate a new set of predicted probabilities, y, that demonstrated very nice calibration results:

[image]

After a bit of research, this sounds very similar to Platt scaling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling), though am unsure if this makes sense in the setting of LASSO logistic regression. Conceptually this sounds like applying a log transformation to a logarithmic model (where under normal circumstances, I expect a normal logistic regression to have a more linear appearance on calibration plots).

Does anyone have a clear idea/explanation of what may be going on and/or if this is OK?